# Change the labelsize - football pitch

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to easily change the size of the label on axis?

```
%matplotlib inline


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mplsoccer.pitch import Pitch
plt.style.use('ggplot')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='uefa',figsize=(16,10),axis=True,label=True, tick = True, 
              line_zorder=2, background_zorder=1, linewidth=4, spot_scale=0.0047)


fig, ax = pitch.draw()
```

Comment: try this:`plt.show()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the acquired label.

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=14)
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=14)
```

[image]